# How to get tesseract to recognize these alphanumeric strings?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, tesseract

Having a hard time getting tesseract to recognize alphanumeric text.  These are not dictionary words, and I've set `load_system_dawg` and `load_freq_dawg` to false as recommended [in the docs](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality).

Sample code showing what I'm doing:

```
// Compile with:  g++ test.cpp $(pkg-config --libs tesseract opencv)

#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <tesseract/genericvector.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    /* Disabling the dictionaries Tesseract uses should increase recognition
     * if most of your text isn't dictionary words.  They can be disabled by
     * setting both of the configuration variables load_system_dawg and
     * load_freq_dawg to false.
     * Source:  https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality
     */
    GenericVector<STRING> key;
    GenericVector<STRING> val;
    key.push_back("load_system_dawg");
    val.push_back("false");
    key.push_back("load_freq_dawg");
    val.push_back("false");
    // also tried setting tosp_min_sane_kn_sp to both large and small values

#if 0
    // unfortunately, this doesn't work in tesseract v4.0
    // https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751
    key.push_back("tessedit_char_whitelist");
    val.push_back("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");
#endif

    std::unique_ptr<tesseract::TessBaseAPI> tess(new tesseract::TessBaseAPI());
    tess->Init(nullptr, "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT, nullptr, 0, &key, &val, false);
    tess->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PageSegMode::PSM_SINGLE_LINE);

    for (const auto filename : {"01.png", "02.png", "03.png", "04.png", "05.png", "06.png", "07.png", "08.png", "09.png", "10.png", "11.png", "12.png"})
    {
        cv::Mat mat = cv::imread(filename);
        tess->SetImage(mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.channels(), mat.step1());
        char *text = tess->GetUTF8Text();
        std::string str;
        if (text != nullptr)
        {
            str = text;
        }
        delete [] text;

        std::cout << "OCR results for " << filename << ":  " << str << std::endl;
        cv::imshow("image", mat);
        cv::waitKey();

    }

    tess->End();

    return 0;
}
```

The images I'm using and the results I'm seeing from tesseract:

- "1K 45" (missing whitespace)
  [image: "1 K 45"]

---

- "1K"
  [image: "1 K 41"]

---

- "ZaP © 13" (top few pixels are missing so this one doesn't surprise me)
  [image: "23P C 13]

---

- "308 8" ('B' vs '8' I understand, but the missing whitespace means we cannot interpret this text)
  [image: "30 B 8"]

---

- "23 B 18"
  [image: "23 B 13"]

---

- "" (blank!?)
  [image: "30 B 9"]

---

- "SZ2EC 5"
  [image: "32 EC 5"]

---

- "SZ2EC 3"
  [image: "32 EC 5"]

---

- "1201" (missing whitespace means we cannot interpret these results)
  [image: "12 O 1"]

---

- "a)"
  [image: "1 C 15"]

---

- "1 € 13"
  [image: "1 C 13"]

---

- "J4E 7"
  [image: "34 E 7"]

I'm not looking for 100% recognition, but I think there are likely some configuration items in tesseract that I could be setting to get better results than what I'm currently seeing.

Comment: Try with leptonica library and use default settings `tess->Init(NULL, "eng")` :and  `Pix *image = pixRead("01.png"); tess->SetImage(image);'

Comment: @seccpur Why would it make a difference if the image is loaded via opencv vs leptonica?

Comment: Earlier tested with default settings and leptonica, the results were fairly accurately.

Comment: @seccpur Whether you load the image byte-by-byte, using libpng, opencv, or with leptonica will make no difference.  The images are the same.  What needs to be tweaked is the settings that control what happens to those images afterwards.